# Task: installdebug not found in the project app

Tags: react-native

I got this error I can't able to fix that 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjCvj.jpg)

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
  --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Any one pls help me...